# How can I check if a word is contained in another string using PHP?

Tags: php, string

Pseudo Code

```
text = "I go to school";
word = "to"
if ( word.exist(text) ) {
    return true ;
else {
    return false ;
}
```

I am looking for a PHP function which returns true if the word exists in the text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: You might find [`s($text)->contains($word)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L93) or [`s($text)->containsIgnoreCase($word)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L105) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You have a few options depending on your needs.  For this simple example, `strpos()` is probably the simplest and most direct function to use.  If you need to do something with the result, you may prefer `strstr()` or `preg_match()`.  If you need to use a complex pattern instead of a string as your needle, you'll want `preg_match()`.

```
$needle = "to";
$haystack = "I go to school";
```

[strpos() and stripos()](http://us.php.net/strpos) method (stripos() is case insensitive):

```
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) echo "Found!";
```

[strstr() and stristr() method](http://us.php.net/strstr) (stristr is case insensitive):

```
if (strstr($haystack, $needle)) echo "Found!";
```

[preg_match method](http://us.php.net/preg_match) (regular expressions, much more flexible but runs slower):

```
if (preg_match("/to/", $haystack)) echo "Found!";
```

Because you asked for a complete function, this is how you'd put that together (with default values for needle and haystack):

```
function match_my_string($needle = 'to', $haystack = 'I go to school') {
  if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

PHP 8.0.0 now contains a str_contains function that works like so:

```
if (str_contains($haystack, $needle)) {
    echo "Found";
}
```

Comment: Non php'ers (like myself) note the double-equals in `!== false` because strpos() may return 0 if a match is found right at the beginning of the string (character position zero).

Comment: couldn't you just do `return (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false);`? It has the exact same result, just a cleaner code

Answer (score 21):

```
function hasWord($word, $txt) {
    $patt = "/(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])" . preg_quote($word, '/') . "(?:$|[^a-zA-Z])/i";
    return preg_match($patt, $txt);
}
```

If $word is "to", this will match:

- "Listen to Me"
- "To the moon"
- "up-to-the-minute"

but not:

- "Together"
- "Into space"

Comment: Perfect solution, as strpos() returns true even if it matches a part of string instead of whole word. Example: $haystack="check that fork"; $needle="for";    Now in this case, strpos() will find a match and return true. But peg_match() won't find 'for' word in the haystack, it will return 0.

Answer (score 15):

use:

```
return (strpos($text,$word) !== false); //case-sensitive
```

or

```
return (stripos($text,$word) !== false); //case-insensitive
```

Answer (score 5):

[strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
<?php
$text = "I go to school";
$word = "to"
$pos = strpos($text, $word);

if ($pos === false) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$text="I go to school";
return (strpos($text, 'to')!== false);
```

[The manual page you need to find the correct usage of strpos](http://www.php.net/strpos)

Answer (score 1):

Another way (besides the strpos examples already given is to use the 'strstr' function:

```
if (strstr($haystack, $needle)) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP 8 New Function str_contains**

```
if (str_contains('Foo Bar Baz', 'Foo')) {
  echo 'Found';
}
```

**OR**

Use `strpos` function in php .

```
$text = "I go to school";
$word = "to"
if (strpos($text,$word) !== false ) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these string functions,

[strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) — Find the first occurrence of a string

[stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) — Case-insensitive strstr()

[strrchr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) — Find the last occurrence of a character in a string

[strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

[strpbrk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) — Search a string for any of a set of characters

If that doesn't help then you should use `preg` regular expression

[preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) — Perform a regular expression match