# Check if string contains a string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to know if how can I check I string (specifically an ip address) if that ip address has the string of x

For example

```
$ip = "66.124.61.23" // ip of the current user
$x = "66.124" // this is the string what I want to check in my $ip.
```

So how can I check $ip if it has the string of $x?

Please do leave a comment if you are having a hard time understanding this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: See [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos).

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a word is contained in another string using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
if (strstr($ip, $x))
{
    //found it
}
```

See also:

- [`stristr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) for a case insenstive version of this function.
- [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos) Find the first occurrence of a string
- [`stripos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string

Comment: `strpos` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos), and if you're specifically looking for the beginning of the string (as in your example):

```
if (strpos($ip, $x) === 0)
```

Or, if you just want to see if it is in the string (and don't care about *where* in the string it is:

```
if (strpos($ip, $x) !== false)
```

Or, if you want to compare the beginning n characters, use [`strncmp()`](http://php.net/strncmp)

```
if (strncmp($ip, $x, strlen($x)) === 0) {
    // $ip's beginning characters match $x
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com
```

Based on $domain, we can determine whether string is found or not (if domain is null, string not found)

***This function is case-sensitive. For case-insensitive searches, use [stristr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php).***

You could also use ***[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)***.

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Also read SO earlier post, ***[How can I check if a word is contained in another string using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php)***

Answer (score 2):

Use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if(strpos($ip, $x) !== false){
    //dostuff
}
```

Note the use of double equals to avoid type conversion.  `strpos` can return `0` (and will, in your example) which would evaluate to false with single equals.