# php string how to find one number in a string of numbers

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a word is contained in another string using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php)

I wish to have some PHP code to check if a certain number appears in a string of numbers, so for example how do I check if the number 7 appears in the number 3275?

I have tried strcmp but I can't work this one out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "7");
if ($pos === false) { // note: three equal signs
    // not found...
}
else{
    //string found
}
```

Comment: Note that 'strrpos' find the last occurance, as opposed to 'strpos' which finds the first appearance. Either function will for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php); you can use it to find where a substring occurs in a string (and, by extension, *whether* it occurs). See the first example for how to do the check correctly.

Answer (score 2):

[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is your friend, php is not strongly typed, so you can consider numbers as strings.

```
$mystring = 3232327;
$findme   = 7;
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The number '$findme' was not found in the number '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The number '$findme' was found in the number '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/strpos

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Find the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

make sure you use " !== false" when comparing the return value to see if it exists (otherwise 7325 would return position 0 and 0 == false) - === and !== are compare value AND type (boolean vs integer)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(stristr('3275', '7') !== false)
{
  // found
}
```

Comment: `if(stristr("3275","7") !== false)
{
  // found
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$phno = 1234567890;
$collect = 4;
$position = strpos($phno, $collect);

if ($position)
    echo 'The number is found at the position'.$position;   
else
    echo 'Sorry the number is not found...!!!';
```