# Check if word is a substring - php

Tags: php

I would like to check if a given string is a substring to another string. For example:

```
$a = 'Hello World!';
$b = 'ell';
```

$b is a substring of $a. Any functions that can check this?

Comment: Did you try to google it?

Comment: Have you considered using Google to search for your question?

Comment: The only thing I found was substr but that works like ("abcdef", -1); right? It doesnt compare 2 strings?

Comment: Try [this](http://bit.ly/1paPnn9)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a word is contained in another string using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strpos()` function to check that

```
    <?php
        if (strpos('Hello World!','ell') !== false) {
        echo 'contains';
    }
   else echo 'not contains';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = 'Hello World!';
$b = 'ell';
if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) {
    echo true; // In string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```