# How to add '@' symbol if it doesn't exist in the field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm outputting a custom user field in Wordpress, which is user's Twitter username. Some users might add it with '@' symbol, some might without. How can I output that field and check if the symbol already exists, if not, add it?

This is code I'm using to output usrename:

```
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('twitter_name'); ?>
```

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/1019169/ will give you some ideas. More specifically, the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$authorMeta = get_the_author_meta('twitter_name');
if (strpos('@', $authorMeta) !== 0) {
    $authorMeta = '@'.$authorMeta;
}
echo $authorMeta;
```

you need to check if `@` is on 1st place, you can do this in many ways

```
<?php
$authorMeta = get_the_author_meta('twitter_name');
if ($authoMeta[0] != '@') {
    $authorMeta = '@'.$authorMeta;
}
echo $authorMeta;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...it might help

```
$a = get_the_author_meta('twitter_name');
$b = explode('@',$a);
if($b[1] == 0){
    echo "@".$a;
}
else{
echo $a;
}
```