# PHP - Exact match string in a sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following function to do a `"exact match"` of a pattern`($searchPat)`
in a sentence `($sourceStr)`

```
function isUsed($sourceStr, $searchPat) {
 if (strpos($sourceStr, $searchPat) !== false) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't do an exact match. I changed the function as follows but this doesn't even execute.

```
function isUsed($sourceStr, $searchPat) {
if (preg_match("~\b[$sourceStr]\b~", $searchPat)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

How could I do an exact match please?

Comment: Take out the `[]`, those list allowed characters. Is `$sourceStr` the sentence to search or the term to find?

Comment: Hello Chris - Thank you. Your understanding is correct. `$sourceStr` is the sentence to search in while `$searchPat` is the item to search for.

Comment: You can use stripos () too.

Comment: Hello Devashish - Thank you. As I've mentioned int he question, `strpos` isn't doing an exact match. Could you please help me with the modified code to do this?

Comment: `stripos` would return false positives. For example if searching for `bee` the word `been` would match.

Comment: this questions seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[]` is a character class. That lists characters you want to allow, for example `[aeiou]` would allow a vowel. Your variables are also in the inverted order, pattern first, then string to match against. Try this:

```
function isUsed($sourceStr, $searchPat) {
     if (preg_match("~\b$searchPat\b~", $sourceStr)) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Additional notes, this is case sensitive, so `Be` won't match `be`. If the values you are passing in are going to have special characters the `preg_quote` function should be used, `preg_quote($variable, '~')`. You also may want to concatenate the variable so it is clear that that is a variable and not part of the regex. The `$` in regex means the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
function isUsed($sourceStr, $searchPat) {
if (preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($sourceStr)."\b/i", $searchPat)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try "preg_match" for matches.

```
$string = 'test';
if ( preg_match("~\btest\b~",$string) )
  echo "matched";
else
  echo "no match";
```

Or try like this

```
if(stripos($text,$word) !== false) 
      echo "no match";
    else
      echo "match";
```

Comment: Thank you  Jalpa. Appreciate your time & help

Comment: @usert4jju7 you are wel come :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
  function isUsed($string_to_search, $source_String) {
    if (preg_match("/$string_to_search/", $source_String)) {
    return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
 }
```

You can change according to your need.

**Case insensitive:** preg_match("/$string_to_search/i", $source_String)
**Boundry condition:** preg_match("/\b$string_to_search\b/i", $source_String)
**Special characters:** if you have any special characters in your string for your safe side replace it with '\special_character'

Comment: Thank you Sahil. Appreciate your help