# PHP Validate Substring Exists with Weird Rule

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate my input in PHP, how to check if @*username* exists in the string in the following valid formats in UTF8?

**Valid:**

- "Hello @username"
- "Hello@username"
- "Hello @username how are you?"

**Invalid**

- "Hello username"
- "Hello @usernamehow are you?"

**The following code works, but claims "@usernamehow" is valid when searching for "@username"**

```
$userMentioned = substr_count($text, $username);
```

Comment: you can use `preg_match("/@username(?=\\s|$)/", $username)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the specific patterns you mention, you could use a simple Regular Expression with a one-sided word boundary:

```
$pattern = '/@username\b/';
$userMentioned = preg_match($pattern, $testString);
```

That will ensure there is no other letters or numbers on the right side, but allows for it on the left side.

Comment: `\b` _may_ be wrong here because it will match `@username+xyz` which _may_ not be what OP wants

Comment: @rock321987 I can't speak to that, but it will definitely work for the data he presented. I can see use-cases both for allow it and not. - Best not to over-engineer the solution unless we know one way or the other. "KISS", and all that :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're basically asking [how to check if a word is present within a string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php). This could be done by using REGEX as rock321987 suggested, or by using `strpos()`:

```
$word = " @username ";
$string = "Hello @username how are you?";

if (strpos($string, $word) !== false) {
    die('Found it');
}
```

I found out that Laravel is using the exact same approach:

```
/**
 * Determine if a given string contains a given substring.
 *
 * @param  string  $haystack
 * @param  string|array  $needles
 * @return bool
 */
function str_contains($haystack, $needles)
{
    foreach ((array) $needles as $needle)
    {
        if ($needle != '' && strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.